# Find the ascending words from the clues

Tags: word, wordplay, english

Ascending words are the words which its letter are written in ascending order.
Each clues below, refers to an ascending word.
Example : Type of meat = "beef".
If we sort the letters [b,e,e,f], the result is the same order "beef".
What are the intended words ?
Then find the last hidden word form these words.

> - out of fashion
> - dialect
> - Similar to Bright
> - inquisitive
> - One who is playfully mischievous
> - a number between 10 and 100
> - a kind of hotel
> - a dynasty of China
> - a kind of fish
> - neither
> - a monetary unit
> - void

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Out of fashion

> <s>Moot?</s> Mossy

A dynasty of china

> Chou (alternate spelling for zhou dynasty)

A kind of fish

> <s>Dory</s> this fits, but eel works better for the meta answer.

Similar to bright

> Glowy

Using the answers provided by everyone, we get:

> `MOSSY`
>  `ACCENT`
>  `GLOWY / GLOSSY`
>  `NOSY`
>  `IMP`
>  `FORTY`
>  `INN`
>  `CHOU`
>  `EEL`
>  `NOR`
>  `CENT`
>  `EMPTY`
>
>  Picking the first letter of each word, it looks like the secret hint is *Magnificence*.

And my answer to that would be

> **Glory**

Comment: I can't see how moot fits (by the definition I know it by, anyway). Would you mind giving, idk, a sentence? :P

Comment: @Asteria : You are right, moot is not the correct word, there is another word with initial M fit better.

Comment: Ah, dang. I had to use a script to find out all eligible m words and google their definition one by one before i finally found the correct answer. I seriously never heard of that word being used that way :P

Answer (score 9):

Augh, looks like @Votbear posted almost an identical answer while I was working on this. (Yes, it took more than an hour..) This answer adds almost nothing to it.

The final answer is most likely

> Glory

It's formed by taking the first letters from these words and interpreting them as a clue

> ```
>  out of fashion                   - Mossy
>  dialect                          - Accent
>  Similar to Bright                - Glowy
>  inquisitive                      - Nosy 
>  One who is playfully mischievous - Imp
>  a number between 10 and 100      - Forty
>  a kind of hotel                  - Inn
>  a dynasty of China               - Ching (Wade-Giles romanization of Qing)
>  a kind of fish                   - Eels
>  neither                          - Nor
>  a monetary unit                  - Cent
>  void                             - Empty
> ```

Comment: At last all the clue answered well.

Answer (score 7):

**Partial Answer**

dialect:

> accent

inquisitive:

> nosy

hotel:

> inn

fish:

> eel

Comment: Ooh, good ones!  (Though I think you're missing a ! in your spoiler tags :)

Answer (score 7):

A number between 10 and 100:

> forty

A dynasty of China:

> Chin

Comment: Isn't it "Qin"?

Comment: @mestackoverflow alternate spelling.  :-)

Comment: Oh ok. (Here are more words to reach the minimum amount)

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer** (being updated as I think of more):

Inquisitive

> nosy

One who is playfully mischievous

> imp

Neither

> nor

Void

> empty

Answer (score 6):

**Partial Answer**
a monetary unit

> Cent

Similar to Bright

> aglow

Answer (score 6):

I have an alternate guess for this,

Similar to Bright

> Glossy